# I would like to push real time data and plot

Tags: vue.js, browser, real-time-data

I am using vue in the browser, code seems fine to me yet it is giving error saying "vue is not defined".

This itself is complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div class="app">
    {{ message }}
  <line-chart></line-chart>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
Vue.component('line-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
        }
      ]
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }

})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello World'
  }
})
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is sample one, though i am using it to plot real time data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html file just include Vue with

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

or:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

and it works.